# how jusched.exe checks for java updates?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, updates

I have learned that **javacpl.exe** is a java control panel for java settings.

Also the **jusched.exe** is `scheduler` and it will check for java updates.

**My questions :**

1. Does anyone knows how `jusched.exe` will check for updates ? What is the secret code behind the sheduler ?
2. Does the jusched.exe user this link to get latest java version http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt  .
3. And if the `jusched.exe` found that version is greater than the current installed java version , It will do for updates ?

Hope I will get a reliable answer here.

Answer (score 2):

That's... that's pretty much it, actually.

Well, I don't know for sure what `jusched.exe` uses to check for an update (it may well be the link you provided), but that's the basic idea—check some source for an update at a predetermined time, and if an update is available, alert the user and begin installing.

It may be possible to get an even better picture of what `jusched.exe` connects to by using a network analyzer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), if you're interested in the source in particular.